# Undefined index notice even though i can get the data

Tags: php, arrays, notice

I'm working with an array that gives me all the info if print_r but it also says that it is an unidentified index.
Code:

```
    foreach ($_SESSION['passo4'] as $key => $value) {
        $x = $data_ref[0]['tipo_refeicao']; //gives me the error
        echo $x; //echoes 1
        print_r($data_ref);
        if($key != 'preco'){
            //Obter info do tipo de vestuário
            $f_r = $dbh->prepare("SELECT tipo_refeicao, preco_acompanhante, preco_participante FROM refeicao WHERE id_extra = '$key'");
            $f_r->execute();
            $data_ref = $f_r->fetchAll();

            echo "<tr><td>".
            datasearch($data_tref, 'tipo_refeicao', $x, 'descricao')
            ."</td>";

            echo "<td>". $value ."</td>";

            echo "<td>". $data_ext[0]['preco'] * $value ."€</td></tr>";
        }
    }
```

Notice

```
Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in C:\xampp\htdocs\Rot.Aventura\eventos\passo5.php on line 96
```

Print_r($data_ref):

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [id_refeicao] => 4 [id_evento] => 11 [tipo_refeicao] => 1 [preco_participante] => 5 [preco_acompanhante] => 6 [limite_pessoa] => 2 ) )
```

die($x): `1`

Should i hide this notice with @ or is there any way to solve this? (Sorry for the portuguese words)

Comment: post `print_r($data_ref)` to see it better

Comment: Leave `[0]` out of your code.

Comment: Yes that code is inside a foreach

Comment: Are'nt you sure it's not something echoed after that displays '1' ? As index '0' does not exist in your array $x should be equal to null. Edit : as it's a loop there might be one step where index 0 exists and others where it does'nt.

Comment: Oh no, the $x is just to see if i get what i want from the array, it's just called once and it gets exactly what i want from the array

Comment: I see too many questions like this. Take the time to learn how to [interpret errors and fix your code](http://jason.pureconcepts.net/2013/05/fixing-php-errors/).

Comment: Can you post all the relevant code ?

Comment: @JasonMcCreary i know the basics of the errors, the thing is that it's showing me a notice saying there is no index but it shows and works fine.

Comment: $data_ref = $f_r->fetchAll(); --> there is probably one step where this does not return what you expect. Print the variable. (Or data_ref is not initialized at first loop step)

Comment: @nicolas that was it, there was an error with my 'dbh->prepare' Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Since you are in a foreach loop you don't have to use index `0`. `foreach` auto increment the index, so on next index `0` is undefined

Please try without index or put $x out of loop

```
foreach ($_SESSION['passo4'] as $key => $value) {
    ...
    $data_ref = $f_r->fetchAll();
    $x = $data_ref['tipo_refeicao']; //gives me the error
```

or

```
foreach ($_SESSION['passo4'] as $key => $value) {
...
$x = $data_ref['tipo_refeicao']; //gives me the error
```

Give it a try

Comment: It was an sql error, thank you for taking your time to answer

Answer (score 0):

The problem was an error with my code:

```
$f_r = $dbh->prepare("SELECT tipo_refeicao, preco_acompanhante, preco_participante FROM refeicao WHERE id_extra = '$key'");
```

Where is id_extra it should be id_refeicao. Thank you for your time and help